# Unknown Error for a bash script!

Tags: perl, bash, scripting

So I have a perl script which takes in 2 arguments.

1. a directory leading to the '.txt' files I am interested in searching through
2. a file that has words in it which I have converted to an array.

#### Perl file (perlstemmer.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(ALLFILES,"/Users/mymacbook/saver/rssFolders/txt") or die "Can't Open: $!\n";
open(TRIGGERFILE,"/Users/mymacbook/trigger.txt") or die "Can't Open: $!\n";

my $line=<>;
my %words;
my $i;
my @triggers =<TRIGGERFILE>;

while(<TRIGGERFILE>) #read each line into $_
{
   chomp @triggers;  # Remove newline from $_
   push @triggers, $_; # add the line to @triggers
   #/puts all txt from trigger.txt into the array @triggers. /
}

while($line ne "")
{
 %words = split(//, $line);
}

foreach $i(@triggers)
{
 if (exists $words{$i})
 {
  return 1;
 } 
 $line= <>; 
 return 0;
}
```

So I this script will return a 1 if the file has a word from the array @triggers and a 0 if it does not....

#### Bash script organise.sh

Then the bash script reads in if it has a 1:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$5

for a in `ls $DIR*`
   do
   b=`basename $a`
   perlStemmer.pl $a >> tmp

   $b = filter.pl tmp
   if [$b == 1]; then
      cp $a ../crimeStories/$b
      echo "$a describes crime"
   else
       echo "$a does NOT describe crime"
   fi

 done;
exit 0;
```

-> So copy the file $a if it returned a 1. and print: that it does describe
Else... if it returns a 0
say it doesn't describe crime and do nothing with it :-)

#### My problem

I'm getting a crazy terminal when I try running this:

```
>./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [perlStemmer.pl: command not found
perlStemmer.pl does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: version.plist: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [version.plist: command not found
version.plist does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: Jennie:: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [Jennie:: command not found
Jennie: does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: Assignment: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [Assignment: command not found
Assignment does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: 1.doc: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [1.doc: command not found
1.doc does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: Document.pdf: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [Document.pdf: command not found
Document.pdf does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: Gers: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [Gers: command not found
Gers does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: polo's: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [polo's: command not found
polo's does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
./organise.sh: line 10: contact: command not found
./organise.sh: line 11: [contact: command not found
contact does NOT describe crime
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl: command not found
```

perlStemmer does exist I have tried adding its full path to it but then the program only seems to search the folder where perlStemmer.pl is.

I can see that it seems to be splitting file names and folder names.

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong or what may be causing this in keep looping?

I'm also getting this:

```
  This (the Directory node) gives a menu of major topics. 
  Typing "d" returns here, "q" exits, "?" lists all INFO commands, "h" 
  gives a primer for first-timers, "mEmacs<Return>" visits the Emacs topic,
  etc.
  In Emacs, you can click mouse button 2 on a menu item or cross reference
  to select it.
  --- PLEASE ADD DOCUMENTATION TO THIS TREE. (See INFO topic first.) ---

* Menu: The list of major topics begins on the next line.

Emacs
* Ada mode: (ada-mode). The GNU Emacs mode for editing Ada.
* Autotype: (autotype). Convenient features for text that you enter frequently
                          in Emacs.
* CC Mode: (ccmode).   Emacs mode for editing C, C++, Objective-C,
                          Java, Pike, and IDL code.
* CL: (cl).             Partial Common Lisp support for Emacs Lisp.
* Dired-X: (dired-x).   Dired Extra Features.
* EUDC: (eudc).   A client for directory servers (LDAP, PH)
* Ebrowse: (ebrowse).   A C++ class browser for Emacs.
* Ediff: (ediff).       A visual interface for comparing and merging programs.
* Emacs: (emacs).       The extensible self-documenting text editor.
* Emacs FAQ: (efaq).    Frequently Asked Questions about Emacs.
* Emacs MIME: (emacs-mime).   The MIME de/composition library.
* Eshell: (eshell).     A command shell implemented in Emacs Lisp.
* Forms: (forms).       Emacs package for editing data bases
                          by filling in forms.
* Gnus: (gnus).         The newsreader Gnus.
* IDLWAVE: (idlwave).   Major mode and shell for IDL and WAVE/CL files.

* MH-E: (mh-e).         Emacs interface to the MH mail system.
* Message: (message).   Mail and news composition mode that goes with Gnus.
* PCL-CVS: (pcl-cvs).   Emacs front-end to CVS.
* RefTeX: (reftex).     Emacs support for LaTeX cross-references and citations.
* SC: (sc).             Supercite lets you cite parts of messages you're
                          replying to, in flexible ways.



* Speedbar: (speedbar).        File/Tag summarizing utility.
* VIP: (vip).           An older VI-emulation for Emacs.
* VIPER: (viper).       The newest Emacs VI-emulation mode.
                          (also, A VI Plan for Emacs Rescue
                           or the VI PERil.)
```

printing in the terminal!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right of the text area where you type your question is a box titled **How to Format**. Worth a read. Please edit your answer to format the code. (Can you edit with rep = 1? Surely you must be able to edit your own question, but I can't remember. If there's no "edit" link under your question, just post a comment and I'll fix it for you.)

Answer (score 1):

This question is incredibly long and superfluous for the actual problem,
indicated by this line:

```
./organise.sh: line 8: perlStemmer.pl
```

The Perl script you include is totally irrelevant, since *it isn't even
running*.  Start with one problem at a time and solve them in turn, so you
don't get overwhelmed with other issues that cannot be solved yet.

Your bash script cannot find perlStemmer.pl. This suggests you are not in the
correct directory when you run the script, as (since you don't provide any
path information), it will only look in the directories in `$PATH` for it.

You might want to check for some error conditions before proceeding with the
execution of the remainder of the bash script, as if the first part didn't
work, you're just going to get garbage for the rest (as you are seeing).

---

Incidentally, there are a few fundamental issues with your script that will prevent it from doing anything useful:

```
my @triggers =<TRIGGERFILE>;
while(<TRIGGERFILE>) #read each line into $_
```

This reads the entire contents of the file into `@triggers`, so this while
loop will terminate immediately, as you are already at the filehandle's end of file.

```
while($line ne "")
```

You have only read one line into `$line` and don't read another, so this line
will either loop forever or do nothing, depending on whether the first line of
the content you pipe on stdin is an empty string (likely the former, since you
haven't chomped a newline from it).

Comment: The shell only looks for perlStemmer.pl in the directories in `$PATH`.  If `.` is not in the path, then it won't look in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ether that you've provided too much information, and that the first error line is telling you most of what the trouble is.

However, there are several possible problems not mentioned:

- The Perl script is not executable; use `chmod +x perlStemmer.pl`.
- The Perl script is not in a directory on your PATH; possibly add '.' to the end of your PATH, or use a path to tell the shell script where to find it:

  - `export PATH=$PATH:.`
  - `./perlStemmer.pl`

Note that in shell scripting, it is conventional to use an exit status of 0 to indicate success and 1 to indicate failure.  Superficially, your Per script those reversed - using 1 to indicate that something was found and 0 to indicate that it was not.  OTOH, your script does not actually use the exit status of 'perlStemmer.pl' so it is not critical.

---

There is some weird shell syntax in use, too, including some stray (superfluous, but not incorrect) semi-colons at the end.

However, the start shows some problems:

```
DIR=$5

for a in `ls $DIR*`
   do
   b=`basename $a`
   perlStemmer.pl $a >> tmp

   $b = filter.pl tmp
   if [$b == 1]; then
```

Of itself, the DIR assignment is fine (though it is sad to make people type 5 arguments when you are only going to use the last, it seems).

The `ls` command may not do what you had in mind; if `$5` is a directory name, then what you're listing is all directories that start with the given name, rather than all files in the sub-directory...it ends up somewhat similar, but is not the same as `ls $DIR/*`, which is probably what you meant.

The next three lines are OK.  At some time in the future, when you've mastered the basics better, we can discuss `trap` for ensuring the `tmp` is not left lying around; for now, that is an unnecessary diversion.

The next line is horribly broken:

```
$b = filter.pl tmp
```

If b currently contains `abcd`, then this line tries to execute the command `abcd` with arguments '=', 'filter.pl' and 'tmp'.  This is unlikely to be what you had in mind; it may also be that one of your files is called 'info' and when this line executes, it executes the 'info' command - which is the last part of your question.

It looks as if you might be seeking the exit status of the result of running 'filter.pl' on the output of perlStemmer.pl - the next line suggests that.  We'll assume that you have PATH and permissions sorted out for that program too.

The test line is badly broken too; if b contains 'abcd', then it will try to execute a command '`[abcd`', and probably won't find it.  You need spaces around the square brackets, in general.

#### Revised shell script

So, you probably want something like this, assuming that 'filter.pl' returns 0 (success) when the file describes a crime and non-zero (failure) otherwise:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$5

for a in `ls $DIR/*`
do
   b=`basename $a`
   perlStemmer.pl $a >> tmp
   if filter.pl tmp
   then
       cp $a ../crimeStories/$b
       echo "$a describes crime"
   else
       echo "$a does NOT describe crime"
   fi
done
exit 0
```

---

And, with `trap` in use:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$5
trap "rm -f tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

for a in `ls $DIR/*`
do
   b=`basename $a`
   perlStemmer.pl $a >> tmp
   $b = filter.pl tmp
   if filter.pl tmp
   then
       cp $a ../crimeStories/$b
       echo "$a describes crime"
   else
       echo "$a does NOT describe crime"
   fi
done
rm -f tmp
trap 0
exit 0
```